# Is it safe to visit Babilonia neighborhood in Rio de Janeiro as a tourist?

Tags: safety, rio-de-janeiro

I read on the internet that it's one of the safe and tourist-friendly favelas.

On the other hand, when I went to Rio and ordered an Uber to go there, two drivers told me they won't enter it because it's too dangerous and unless I have friends inside I shouldn't go inside either.

I've only been to Vidigal favela, which has a lot of tourist infrastructure and I have confirmed before with locals that it's safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a question that really can receive a canonical answer, as 'safe' means different things to different people and what might be safe for me might not be safe for you.

If you mean the area at the end of Leme beach, I'd say it's not less safe than, say, nearby Santa Marta, but everyone's mileage will vary.

Your Ubers not wanting to go in is more likely because of the drivers being overly cautious. But, as obvious outsiders, perhaps they have a point.
You can take an Uber to Leme and then walk up.

I think the Urca side is used for rock climbing, which would imply they get up/down via the favela. Which would suggest this favela is comparatively safe.